# @ControllerAdvice not triggered for Jackson errors

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson2

I have a @RestController which has a POST method and if I get a data error saving, then my @ControllerAdvice fires; however, if my error is from Jackson deserialization which is triggered by the @Valid annotation, it is never reaching the @ControllerAdvice.  What is the recommended way to handle @Valid exceptions?

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/principal/add")
  public PrincipalDto addPrincipal(@Valid @RequestBody PrincipalDto 
principal) {
    return principalService.addPrincipal(principal);
  }
```

Exception Controller:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = {RestController.class})
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest 
request) {
    ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(ex);
    return handleExceptionInternal(
        ex, exceptionResponse, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 
request);
  }
}
```

The exception I see in the logs if I try to pass invalid data to a LocalDate field is:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON 
parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from 
String "string": Text 'string' could not be parsed at index 0; nested 
exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "string":  
Text 'string' could not be parsed at index 0
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 18] (through reference 
chain: xxx.dto.PrincipalDto["dateOfBirth"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by pulling out handleExceptionInternal out of the handleExceptions method:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest 
request) {
    ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(ex);
    return handleExceptionInternal(
            ex, exceptionResponse, new HttpHeaders(), 
HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
      Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, 
WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ExceptionResponse(ex), headers, status);
  }
}
```

Comment: Same type of json deser problem but your solution does not work for me.